# MySQL Left Join with child IsDeleted Flag

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have been searching google, but can't seem to exactly figure out my case. What I am trying to do is join a customer who has a list of jobs associated to him. I want the customer and any "active" jobs, in other words they haven't been deleted. The deleted flag is whether or not the datedeleted column is null or not.

So Lets say I have a table Customer:

```
ID - Name
1  - Joe Blow
2  - John Smith
```

And I also have a table of Jobs

```
ID  -  CustomerId  -  Name         -  DateDeleted
1   -      1          Build Fence         NULL
2   -      2        - Clean Yard   -   25/12/2014
```

What I want to do is get a customer with a list of their jobs. Now I know that if I do a join with Jow Blow it works fine, but it doesn't work when I want to get John Smith, it doesn't return any rows because I am checking the Deleted flag which then doesn't return any rows for jobs which in turn doesn't return any customer.

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, j.name as JobName from customer c
left join job j on c.id = j.CustomerId
where c.id = :id AND j.date_deleted IS NULL
```

And I want a results to be either:

```
Id  -  Name        -  JobName
1   -  Jow Blow    -  Build Fence
```

or

```
Id  -  Name        -  JobName
2   -  John Smith  -  NULL
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `WHERE` clause.  When you add the `AND j.date_deleted IS NULL`, you are turning your `OUTER JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.  You will need to move this condition to the `ON` clause of your `OUTER JOIN`.

Use this instead:

```
Select      c.id, 
            c.name, 
            j.name      As JobName 
From        customer    c
Left Join   job         j   On  c.id = j.CustomerId
                            And j.date_deleted IS NULL
Where       c.id = :id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with this approach.As per my understanding you want to show all those jobs which has no         date.

```
      select e.Id,e.Name,( case  when j.date is null then j.name else null end) as Jobprocess from 
      customer e
      left join job j on e.Id=j.custId
```